# Creating big file on Windows

Tags: c, windows, file, file-io

I need to create big relatively big (1-8 GB) files.  What is the fastest way to do so on Windows using  C or C++ ? I need to create them on the fly and the speed is really an issue. File will be used for storage emulation i.e will be access randomly in different offsets and i need that all storage will be preallocate but not initialized, currently we are writing all storage with dummy data and it's taking too long.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the Win32 API, [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx), [SetFilePointerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365542(VS.85).aspx), [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531(VS.85).aspx), and [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211(VS.85).aspx).  In that same order.

The trick is in the SetFilePointerEx function.  From MSDN:

> Note that it is not an error to set
>   the file pointer to a position beyond
>   the end of the file. The size of the
>   file does not increase until you call
>   the SetEndOfFile, WriteFile, or
>   WriteFileEx function.

Windows explorer actually does this same thing when copying a file from one location to another.  It does this so that the disk does not need to re-allocate the file for a fragmented disk.

Comment: This will work fast only on NTFS and exFAT, not on FAT32, FAT16 ..
This is because these file system have an "initialized size"

Comment: `SetEndOfFile()` can lead to serious delays when writing to the file. If you write into the middle of the file, Windows will zero out all blocks that have not yet been written to, up to the location of the write. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/22/10215053.aspx (And I can personally confirm this. I've witnessed the effect myself when writing an IO benchmark application.)

Comment: Your solution initializes to zeros, please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25120850/1237747).

Answer (score 3):

Check out [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx).

They very much match the use case you describe, high performance and random access.

I believe they don't need to be created as large files. You just set a large max size on them and they will be expanded when you write to parts you haven't touched before.

Comment: Using memory mapped files also introduces more complications: errors are reported via structured exceptions instead of function return values, and you won't be able to map an entire 8 GB file into memory on 32-bit Windows because you only have 2 GB of virtual address space (or 3 GB if you're lucky).

Comment: You'll definitely need to use a (or multiple if you are using many parts of the file independently) window to map what's relevant into memory. It's not like you have the entire file accessible if using standard file IO anyway. It just done using fseeks rather than changing what's mapped to memory.

Answer (score 2):

Use "fsutil" command:

E:\VirtualMachines>fsutil file createnew
Usage : fsutil file createnew  
   Eg : fsutil file createnew C:\testfile.txt 1000

Reagds

P.S. it is for Windows: 2000/XP/7

Answer (score 2):

Well [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455302/1237747) solution is not bad, but the thing you are looking for is [SetFileValidData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As MSDN sais:

> The SetFileValidData function allows you to avoid filling data with
>   zeros when writing nonsequentially to a file.

So this always leave disk data as it is, `SetFilePointerEx` should set all data to zeros, so big allocation takes some time.

Comment: Note that `SetFileValidData` is one huge security risk, which is why you need a privilegued process to be able to use this function, too. The solution proposed by Laserallan (memory mapped files) is much preferrable if you have enough address space. Creating a mapping of an arbitrary size is both fast _and_ safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NTFS then [sparse files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365564(VS.85).aspx) are the way to go:

> A file in which much of the data is
>   zeros is said to contain a sparse data
>   set. Files like these are typically
>   very large—for example, a file
>   containing image data to be processed
>   or a matrix within a high-speed
>   database. The problem with files
>   containing sparse data sets is that
>   the majority of the file does not
>   contain useful data and, because of
>   this, they are an inefficient use of
>   disk space.
>
> The file compression in the NTFS file
>   system is a partial solution to the
>   problem. All data in the file that is
>   not explicitly written is explicitly
>   set to zero. File compression compacts
>   these ranges of zeros. However, a
>   drawback of file compression is that
>   access time may increase due to data
>   compression and decompression.
>
> Support for sparse files is introduced
>   in the NTFS file system as another way
>   to make disk space usage more
>   efficient. When sparse file
>   functionality is enabled, the system
>   does not allocate hard drive space to
>   a file except in regions where it
>   contains nonzero data. When a write
>   operation is attempted where a large
>   amount of the data in the buffer is
>   zeros, the zeros are not written to
>   the file. Instead, the file system
>   creates an internal list containing
>   the locations of the zeros in the
>   file, and this list is consulted
>   during all read operations. When a
>   read operation is performed in areas
>   of the file where zeros were located,
>   the file system returns the
>   appropriate number of zeros in the
>   buffer allocated for the read
>   operation. In this way, maintenance of
>   the sparse file is transparent to all
>   processes that access it, and is more
>   efficient than compression for this
>   particular scenario.

Comment: No - he needs to pre-allocate the extents.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that your question is tagged with Windows, and Brian R. Bondy gave you the best answer to your question if you know for certain you will not have to port your application to other platforms. However, if you might have to port your application to other platforms, you might want to do something more like what Adrian Cornish proposed as the answer for the question "How to create file of “x” size?" found at [How to create file of "x" size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775027/how-to-create-file-of-x-size).

```
FILE *fp=fopen("myfile", "w");
fseek(fp, 1024*1024, SEEK_SET);
fputc('\n', fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Of course, there is an added twist. The answer proposed by Adrian Cornish makes use of the fseek function which has the following signature.

```
int fseek ( FILE * stream, long int offset, int origin );
```

The problem is that you want to create a very large file with a file size that is beyond the range of a 32-bit integer. You need to use the 64-bit equivalent of fseek. Unfortunately, on different platforms it has different names.

The header file LargeFileSupport.h found at http://mosaik-aligner.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/src/CommonSource/Utilities/LargeFileSupport.h offers a solution to this problem.

This would allow you to write the following function.

```
#include "LargeFileSupport.h"
/* Include other headers. */

bool createLargeFile(const char * filename, off_type size)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!fp)
    {
        return false;
    }
    fseek64(fp, size, SEEK_SET);
    fputc('\n', fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I thought I would add this just in case the information would be of use to you.