# Formatting file on windows

Tags: c, windows, linux, file, file-io

Following [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455297/creating-big-file-on-windows) about creating files.
After fast creation of large file, now i need to create a file system on this file. 
How can i create something like [Loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) on Linux. After this i guess formatting will be really easy. Any alternative method (instead mounting) for formatting file to different FAT (12/32) and ext3 are welcomed :)

I would prefer to do it in C/C++, but in the worst case i can use external commands i.e 
running ready executable from my application.

**Edit:**
It seems like Windows does not allow this natively, so it will be best to find some application that doing **exactly**  this i.e mounting file as a files system. Otherwise i have a problem with open source licenses.

Comment: Are you looking to create an image of a partition or filesystem?  The question isn't too clear (or I'm reading it wrong).

Comment: I'm looking to mounting file as disk, after this i can do whatever i want i.e partition, file system , both ...

Comment: Have you looked into any freeware that can create and mount ISOs?  I know that such tools exist, but I don't recall if they let you mount them as *writable* disks...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [TrueCrypt's source code](http://www.truecrypt.org/). It is a open-source disk encryption software for Windows Vista/XP, Mac OS X, and Linux. It can create a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real disk.

Therefore its source code must contain "create a file system on this file" part.

Comment: For example, try `ack FormatFat` at the source tree root.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising i will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

[Eldos](http://eldos.com/) make a component, [Solid File System](http://eldos.com/solfs/) that might do what you're looking for

Comment: no it's not i don't need new file system, i need ability to create one using file instead of disk. It's really easy on linux using mount -o loop ...

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer, but might be related enough for you to be interesting:

Windows 7 should be able to [boot from a VHD (virtual hard disk)](http://blogs.technet.com/aviraj/archive/2009/01/18/windows-7-boot-from-vhd-first-impression-part-2.aspx) so if you look for a Windows-Like approach to this problem, this might lead you in the right direction.