# FileStream.SetLength(long length) too slow when length is in gigabytes

Tags: c#, performance, file-io

I need to write a small tool to eat up a disk's free space (just leaving a few Kilo Bytes) to test some "low disk space" use cases. The code:

```
new FileStream(filename).SetLength(remaining free bytes - 1024); //leaving 1KB's free space
```

But `FileStream.SetLength(long length)` is too slow if the length is in gigabytes, is just as slow as copying big HD movies to the disk. (**Edit: Sorry I just realize that I experienced this only when writing to removable flashes, if write to other local drives, the speed is fast enough.**)

So I wonder, is there a faster way to write blank files (that is, filled with zeros)? Code in C/C++ is also welcome.
Or is there other trick that I can test the "low disk space" cases without having to write blank files?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be any faster?

Comment: Why not create a VM with a really small disk and test on that?

Comment: Also, your approach might not even be possible, depending on the fragmentation of the disk.

Comment: @leppie Because I think unlike copying bytes from source file to the new file, my need is just a blank file that occupying disk space, no buffer read/write operations, that's why I expect it to be faster.

Comment: @kennyzx: reading is faster than writing normally, so that is never going to be the bottleneck. Except using what Matthew Watson said.

Answer (score 4):

You can create large files without writing to them via the Windows API call [SetFileValidData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

However, note that it will NOT fill the file with zeros (which is why it is faster). Also, READ CAREFULLY the documentation for that function, since there are security implications.

Comment: Looks very promising, i will try it later to see the difference.

Comment: Unfortunately the app requires the SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME privilege to call this API... which a normal one does not have.

Answer (score 0):

After a google search I was directed to this SO question: 
[Creating big file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455297/creating-big-file-on-windows)

That answers my question.